# how to write the script for image corner degree calculation?

Tags: python, rotation, computer-vision, opencv

I have over 100 images that each of them is in different angle. I have written an basic python code to rotate each of the image one by one from any angle to zero degree ( I mean making them flat). The python code that I have attached is a simple code and unfortunately it doesn't automatically find the angle and it does not make it exact zero. Any time for any of the image I should find the angle and run the code for many time to make it zero (sometimes I am not able to make it exactly flat or what we celled zero degree). According to the images that I have attached, image1 is one of the sample image as an input and image_2 is the rotated image that I want to have at the end as an output. 
I would like to ask anyone that can help me to modify the current code or provide me with the new python code (which I prefer the new code)that I can make my images rotate from any angle to zero degree.
please feel free to ask me for more explanation if you want.

my opencv-python code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('image1.tif')
num_rows, num_cols = img.shape[:2]
rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((num_cols/2, num_rows/2),69.4, 1)
img_rotation = cv2.warpAffine(img, rotation_matrix, (num_cols, num_rows))
cv2.imshow('Rotation', img_rotation)
cv2.imwrite('image_2.tif',img_rotation)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Note: input and output images deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's definitely not the most robust method, but perhaps an option would be to:

1. assume that the boundary is all black
2. identify the top-most (x0,y0) / right-most (x1,y1) corners of the image
3. calculate the angle of rotation as `alpha = math.atan2(x1-x0,y1-y0)`

I downloaded your figure (it was converted to png on imgur) and tested the procedure with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv2
import math

import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test.png')
H, W = img.shape[:2]

x0,y0 = None,None
x1,y1 = None,None

#scan all rows starting with the first
for i in range(0, H):
    row = img[i].sum(axis=1)
    s = np.sum(row)
    if s:
        #if there is at least one non-black pixel, mark
        #its position
        x0 = np.max(np.where(row>0))
        y0 = i
        break

#scan all columns starting with the right-most one
for j in range(W-1,-1,-1):
    col = img[:,j,:].sum(axis=1)
    s = np.sum(col)
    if s:
        #mark the position of the first non-black pixel
        x1 = j
        y1 = np.min(np.where(col>0))
        break

dx = x1 - x0
dy = y1 - y0

alpha = math.atan2(dx, dy) / math.pi * 180

rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((W/2, H/2), -alpha, 1)
img_rotation = cv2.warpAffine(img, rotation_matrix, (W, H))
cv2.imwrite('image_2.tif',img_rotation)
```

EDIT:

The previous method can be inaccurate in case the "corner" pixel is black as well so that the calculated angle is then biased. Slightly more accurate approach could be as follows:

1. determine the "upper" boundary of the rectangle (i.e., the coordinates of the pixels defining the edges)
2. take the edge the projection of which on the x-axis is longer
3. fit the coordinates in order to calculate the slope of the line defining the edge

The implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv2
import math

import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test.png')
H, W = img.shape[:2]

data = []
for j in range(0, W):
    col = img[:,j,:].sum(axis=1)
    s = np.sum(col)
    if not s:
        continue

    for i in range(0, H):
        if col[i] > 0:
            data.append((j, i))
            break

y_min, min_pos = None, None
for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(data):
    if y_min is None or y < y_min:
        y_min = y
        min_pos = idx

N = len(data)
if min_pos > N - min_pos:
    data = data[:min_pos]
else:
    data = data[min_pos:]

data = np.asarray(data).T
coeffs = np.polyfit(data[0], data[1], 1)
alpha = math.atan(coeffs[0]) / math.pi * 180

print(alpha)

rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((W/2, H/2), alpha, 1)
img_rotation = cv2.warpAffine(img, rotation_matrix, (W, H))
cv2.imwrite('image_2.tif',img_rotation)
```

Comment: ewcz@ Thanks for your comments and code. I have tried your code but it look like the  rotated image is not exactly 0 degree. would you please let me know if there is anything that i need to do to make it exact zero. thanks

Comment: @FredGrahambel I have included slightly different approach (calculating the angle from the slope of the longest edge), it might be more accurate...

Comment: @ewczThanks a lot for replying quick. The function working fine. I do appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

another way to find the angle is (asuming that the image is over a black background):

1. Convert the image to grayscale
2. Segmentate the image using a threshold
3. Find the contours of the image
4. Find the parameters of the ellipse that fit the contour

   ```
   import cv2
   import numpy as np

   image = cv2.imread("DlYEa.png")

   gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

   num_rows, num_cols = image.shape[:2]
   _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

   img, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

   cnt = contours[0]
   (x, y), (Ma, ma), angle = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)

   angle = int(angle - 90)

   rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((num_cols/2, num_rows/2), angle, 1)
   img_rotation = cv2.warpAffine(image, rotation_matrix, (num_cols, num_rows))

   cv2.imshow("rotation", img_rotation)
   cv2.waitKey()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   ```

Comment: Once@ Thank you for replying to my question. I have tried your code and i faced error since i am not that much good in python to fix the error. would you please look at the following error that i got recently and help me to fix it. Thanks. error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ImageRotation.py", line 11, in <module>
    img, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack